# Python MySQL if variable does not exists still submit

Tags: python, mysql

I'm doing some queries ( inserts ) to a database based on some input.
However not all the times I get all the data from the user. I still would like though to insert the data that I received. I have a table with close to
10 columns but in the data I also have some arrays.

When I'm trying to insert something I get an exception that the say `input['name']` does not exists and the query is not executed.

Is there some way to quickly manage that? If a variable does isn't defined simply throw a warning like in PHP and not break the whole loop.

New to python and only thing I can think of is to check for every single variable but I'd really hope there's something more simpler than this and quicker.

Comment: You can add default value to the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `input.get('name')`

From the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

```
Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default.
If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [exception handling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html). It sounds like you need to use an try-except-else where you're making use of `input['name']`